# Prevent Grid from expanding to fit content, whilst allowing user to resize window

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, grid, resize

In my WPF project, I have a ItemsControl within a Grid, which exists within a UserControl (and ultimately a Window). I want the window to be a certain size by default, and want the user to be able to expand the window if they want (so cannot force a specific window size).

The issue is, when the ItemsControl gets populated, the window will resize to the maximum screen size. This is incredibly annoying, as I want it to be bound by the window size, not to scale to the content size.

How can I achieve this?

GIF Demonstration of problem: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rJrJl.jpg

```
<UserControl x:Class="TribeCast.Windows.PlaylistGenerationWizard.SetupSlide.SetupSlideView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:TribeCast.Converters"
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
         xmlns:playlistGenerationWizard="clr-namespace:TribeCast.Windows.PlaylistGenerationWizard"
         d:DesignHeight="491"
         d:DesignWidth="678"
         mc:Ignorable="d" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" MinHeight="425" MinWidth="600">
<Grid Margin="0" Background="{DynamicResource BackgroundGrey}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <RowDefinition Height="40"  />
        <RowDefinition Height="32"  />
        <RowDefinition Height="32" />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition Height="42" />
        <RowDefinition Height="42" />

    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Label Grid.Row="0"
        Margin="6,0,0,0" Content="Playlist Setup" FontSize="18.667" Foreground="{DynamicResource TextLight}" Padding="0" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1"
        Margin="6,5,0,5" Foreground="{DynamicResource TextDark}"><Run Text="Please define how many duplicates of each item should appear in the playlist"/></TextBlock>
    <Grid Grid.Row="2"
        Margin="0" Height="30" Background="{DynamicResource RowItem}">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="105" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="60" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="105" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0"
            Margin="5,0"
            Text="Broadcast Name" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="{DynamicResource TextLight}" />
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1"
            Margin="5,0"
            Text="Original Duration" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="{DynamicResource TextLight}" />
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="2"
            Margin="5,0"
            Text="Repeat" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="{DynamicResource TextLight}" />
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="3"
            Margin="5,0"
            Text="Total Duration" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="{DynamicResource TextLight}" />
    </Grid>

    <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="3"
        VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <ItemsControl x:Name="Items"
            Margin="0" Background="{DynamicResource VeryDarkGradientIndented}" />
    </ScrollViewer>
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="4"
        Orientation="Horizontal" Background="{DynamicResource BackgroundGrey}">
        <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="6,0,0,0" Foreground="{DynamicResource TextLight}"><Run Text="Genera"/><Run Text="t"/><Run Text="ed Playlist Ordering:"/></TextBlock>
        <RadioButton Content="Repeated"
            GroupName="GenerationAlgorithm"
            IsChecked="{Binding GenerationAlgorithm, ConverterParameter={x:Static playlistGenerationWizard:GenerationAlgorithm.InPlace}, Converter={converters:EnumToBooleanConverter}}"
            ToolTip="The playlist will be generated without changing the original order." VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="6,0" />
        <RadioButton Content="Evenly Distributed"
            GroupName="GenerationAlgorithm"
            IsChecked="{Binding GenerationAlgorithm, ConverterParameter={x:Static playlistGenerationWizard:GenerationAlgorithm.EvenlyDistributed}, Converter={converters:EnumToBooleanConverter}}"
            ToolTip="The playlist will be generated by evenly distributing each item. Where possible, no broadcasts will play back to back." VerticalAlignment="Center" Padding="0" Margin="6,0" Cursor="" />

        <RadioButton Content="Random"
            GroupName="GenerationAlgorithm"
            IsChecked="{Binding GenerationAlgorithm, ConverterParameter={x:Static playlistGenerationWizard:GenerationAlgorithm.Random}, Converter={converters:EnumToBooleanConverter}}"
            ToolTip="The playlist will be generated in a completely random order with no guarantees about back to back play." VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="6,0" />
    </StackPanel>
    <DockPanel Margin="0"  Grid.Row="5" Background="{DynamicResource TransparentWhite}">
        <TextBlock
            Text="{Binding TotalDuration, StringFormat='Total Duration: \{0\} '}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="300" Height="42" d:LayoutOverrides="LeftPosition, RightPosition" Margin="6,0,0,0" />
        <TextBlock
            Text="{Binding TotalItems, StringFormat='Items: \{0\} '}" Height="42" Margin="0,0,6,0" Width="300" DockPanel.Dock="Right" HorizontalAlignment="Right" FlowDirection="RightToLeft" ToolTip="Original number of items to duplicate" />
    </DockPanel>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Could you please post the code of the parent container of the instance of this user control?

Answer (score 0):

Try binding the `ScrollViewer`'s `Height` to its parent `ActualHeight`. Example:

```
<ScrollViewer Grid.Row="3" 
              Height={Binding ActualHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Grid}}
              VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
   <ItemsControl x:Name="Items" Margin="0" Background="{DynamicResource VeryDarkGradientIndented}" />
</ScrollViewer>
```

EDIT: Actually, this might not be your case as you have multiple controls in the view.

Have you tried setting the `Height` of the corresponding `RowDefinition` to `"*"`?

```
<RowDefinition Height="*" />
```